# Convert a timestamp EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT format to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' format?

Tags: java, date

I want to convert the timestamp `Wed, 20 Feb 2013 11:41:23 GMT` to `2013-02-20T11:41:23Z` . How can I do this? I want to ISO-8601 in UTC format(2013-20-02T04:51:03Z).

My code is below

```
Date date=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
String strDate = date.toString();
Date dt = formatter.parse(strDate );
System.out.println("Date " +dt);
```

Output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 20 03:50:03 PST 2013"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code acquires the current date, converts it to string as the default toString() implementation does, then you try to parse it using a different format, and surprise, it fails. This is what it is expected to do!

Comment: the coma "," doesn't appear are you sure strDate contains that? Wed Feb 20 03:50:03 PST 2013 appears on the exception

Answer (score 3):

Its your format what is wrong, use:
    **"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"** that is what is comming out of the exception, in the question you have **"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"** for Wed, 20 Feb 2013 11:41:23 GMT

Try:

```
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
        String strDate = date.toString();
        Date dt = null;
        try {
            dt = formatter.parse("Wed Feb 20 03:50:03 PST 2013");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Date " + dt);
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which has built in support for parsing and outputting ISO-format date strings.

```
new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 DateFormatters, one for parsing and one for output. You have the one for output.

EDIT: Output works like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
String output = formatter.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Date " + output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
format.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone ("UTC"));
Date date = new Date ();
System.out.println ("Date is: " + format.format (date));
```

Comment: I want to return "convertedDate" value is Date format not a String format

Comment: @AMathi Then just return `sourceFormat.parse (date)`.

Comment: @AMathi Looks like I didn't understand what you wanted.  Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `Date` object. You just need to [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) it to `String`.

`formatter.format(date)` should give you the desired result if the pattern in the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor is valid.

With the above implementation your code looks like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
String dt = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println("Date " + dt);
```

Which results in an output like - `Date 2013-02-20T17:39:45Z`.